# How to create inline h1 and span, and align span to end?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create the simplest react app, and want to create (using bootstrap 4) header, that will have 2 parts,the first part will be at the left side, and the second part will be at the end. I have this code:

```
 <div className='container justify-content-center'>
    <h1>Todo App <span className='d-flex justify-content-end text-secondary'> today tasks:</span></h1>
</div>
```

And as result, i have:

```
Todo App
          today tasks:
```

But i want to have result, like this (without new line):

```
Todo App     today tasks:
```

Comment: remove `d-flex justify-content-end` and try `ml-auto` instead

Comment: Thx, but i wanted to align to end

Comment: replace `justify-content-center` by `d-flex`

Comment: doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I just need to make something, like this:

```
<div className='app-header d-flex'>
    <h1>Todo App </h1>
    <span className="text-secondary">today tasks: </span>
</div>
```

and create the css rule:

```
.app-header {
    align-items: flex-end;
  }
```

Comment: I would follow this answer, your markup is describing two different types of data, a heading and current task list / count. Semantically they are different 

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the class justify-content-between.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container row justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <span> part</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-baseline">
    <h1>Todo App</h1>
    <span class="ml-auto text-secondary">today tasks:</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires a nested flex container. You can use a `.row` for the parent flex container and `.col` for the child flex items, the second of which will also be our child flex container with `.col.d-flex.justify-content-end`. I added `.h1` to match the style of the `<h1>` tag so it renders the same as it would inside the heading as you had in your code.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="col">Todo App</h1>
    <div class='col d-flex justify-content-end'>
      <span class='h1 text-secondary'>today tasks:</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```